# find longest substring in alphabetical order?

Tags: python-3.x

First, I'm not asking how to do it. Second, I'm a newbie to python, so I don't really know if there's any simpler way of doing this. I tried to write a code that does this, but am unable to move any further. I'm currently stuck at:

```
#init variables
s = input("enter string")
temp =""
temp1 = ""
max_len = 0
#enumerate loop:
for i in range(len(s)):
    #if in alphabetical order (I replaced this with a while loop)
    while s[i] < s[i+1]:
        temp1 += s[i:i+1]
        #if current sub len > max sub len:
    if len(temp1) > max_len:
        #store new sub indices
        temp += temp1
        #else (I dropped this part coz I don't know how to write the next line
            #move temp index
#print max sub found
print(temp)
```

The comment lines show the pseudo code I'm following. When I run this code, the interpreter stays as it is without giving any output (what seems like an infinite loop).

Instead of giving any other method of solving this, please tell me what's wrong in this code (or method) and how I can improve this.

Comment: The condition in your while loop never changes.

Comment: (There are other issues and potential improvements, too, but you'll at least discover the issues over you fix the infinite loop.)

Comment: @user1093967 I dont get how it forms an infinite loop. It stays true only when order of first letter is less than second letter. It should become false when order of first letter is greater than second letter (shouldn't it?)

Comment: @completeley newbie Sorry, I missed your reply. Your while loop condition is predicated on `s`, but only `temp1` is modified in your while loop body.